# How to make CTRL + / toggle a comment in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c#, visual-studio-2012

How can I make <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> toggle a comment in Visual Studio, as it does with XCode and Eclipse?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Toggle single line comment and toggle block comment commands [have been added in VS 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.1#net-productivity) for C#

You can change the shortcut for these commands to whatever you want in **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard**, search for **Edit.ToggleBlockComment** or **Edit.ToggleLineComment**.

Comment: Oddly, they do not work, not even the defaults, in VS 16.2.2. The error "`The key combination (Ctrl-K, Ctrl-/) is bound to command (Toggle Line Comment) which is not currently available.`" appears at the bottom in the status bar for the default keystrokes, and it doesn't even do that much if you use a custom one.  For now, I'll be giving the "Toggle Comment" plugin a try.

Comment: This did work for me and if you have VS 2019 is the best solution, actually, is THE solution. VS 12.2.5

Comment: this should be the contemporary answer for VS 2019.

Comment: @orionelenzil Done :)

Comment: This still works in VS 2022. It's insane that this isn't a default yet.

Comment: I also had to set `Use new shortcut in:` to `Text Editor`

Comment: Get this to the top: In C#, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> creates breakpoints: breakpoints don't respond to `Edit.ToggleBlockComment` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Comment: For me VS2022 this method works for any shortcut key I tried EXCEPT for control+/ ... this may be something to do with having resharper installed.

Comment: Sorry, an update...setting the shortcut globally was finicky (only worked on some shortcuy combinations). It has to be set on TEXTEDITOR. Then it appears to work on any combination. Nothing to do with resharper.

Comment: @MartyMacGyver in `Visual studio 2022` you also need to install the `workload for ASP.net and Webdevelopment` to use those shortcut keys. I've posted an answer about this below.

Comment: The best solution I found was to first remove the shortcuts for `Edit.InsertComment` `Edit.ToggleBlockComment` and `Edit.ToggleLineComment` as VS would shuffle around shortcuts and mess things up.
Then I added `CTRL+/` to `Edit.CommentSelection` and `CTRL+Shift+/` to `Edit.UncommentSelection`. 

The reason for doing this was I found the `toggle` calls would fail on a selection with an existing comment nested in.

Comment: can someone confirm that this option is removed from both 2017 and 2022 versions for C++ as of now?

Answer (score 58):

You can't make it toggle without going into either a macro or other VS extension.

However, I always setup VS to comment with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and uncomment to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

You can customize the keyboard shortcuts by going int the "Tools" menu and selecting "Options".   Then select "Keyboard" from the "Environment" branch.  From there you can bind the `Edit.CommentSelection` and `Edit.UncommentSelection` commands to whichever keyboard shortcuts you'd like.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, and still works in Aug 2020

Comment: Still works on vs 2019, win11 in  Oct 2023! After trying so many methods :(

Answer (score 48):

Here is a plugin to have the almighty "Toggle Comment" command...

1- Download and Install > https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.ToggleComment

2- Restart VS

3- Go to "Tools > Options... > Environment > Keyboard"

4- Search for the command "ToggleComment" & Bind it to your favorite key

5- Enjoy

(Thank you, I had gave up but finally found this easy way to do it ;D)

Comment: Doesn't work in 2019

Comment: The secret to making this work was selecting `TextEditor` rather than `global` before pressing `Assign`.

Comment: @Herrgott Support for 2019 was _supposedly_ added in v1.8

Comment: @Gulzar confirmed, but what a stupid solution

Answer (score 28):

If you have ReSharper installed (and using VS without it is/was tedious), you can assign a single key to the command `ReSharper.ReSharper_LineComment`.

For instance, I bind the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl-K, Ctrl-C` to the command, and then if I use it on a line that is uncommented, it comments it, and if the line is commented, it will uncomment it.

[image]

Comment: so to directly answer the original question, assign `CTRL + /` to `ReSharper.ReSharper_LineComment`

Comment: You can also create custom shortcuts using above procedure by placing keys inside 'Press shortcuts keys', step by step procedure here: https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/useful-visual-studio-shortcuts-comment-remove-comment-collap/309

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, VS2019 has finally introduced alternative keyboard mapping schemes.
They're available at `Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`.
I've been looking for a solution for toggle comment shortcut problem and I got a whole surprise package. This is more than I wanted.

[image: Keyboard mapping options in vs]

Comment: The Visual Studio Code mappings are indeed the best way to go about this!

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> will comment one or more selected lines.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> will uncomment one or more selected lines.

You can get toolbar icons that will do this by adding the "Text Editor" toolbar. In the toolbar area right-click and select "Text Editor" This will add a strip of icon buttons like this:

[image]

You can customize this strip by selecting the dropdown at the end of the ribbon:

[image]

To edit the keyboard combination go to Tools-Options and select Keyboard under the Environment tree. Here you can change the keys used to trigger the Comment and Uncomment actions:

[image]

Comment: In a default install this shortcut will just comment, not uncomment.

Comment: Clarified key combinations

Comment: Edit.CommentSelection doesn't show up in VisualStudio 2015 community edition.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Resharper, there is an almost identical alternative:

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

By using this single shortcut, you can simply toggle between commenting/uncommenting code.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Code 2019, this can be done by:

1. Enter `hotkeys` in the IDE search field and click `Change hotkeys and keyboard shortcuts`.
2. In `Show commands containing`, search for and select `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.GenerateDocumentationComments`.
3. Click `Remove` on the right side of `Shortcuts for selected command`, where `ctrl+/` is currently selected.
4. In `Show commands containing`, search for and select `Edit.ToggleLineComments`.
5. Click the `Press shortcut keys` box and press `ctrl` + `/`.
6. Click `Assign` to assign the new hotkey.

Note that unbinding the already existing function for `ctrl` + `/` is necessary for this to work.

Comment: Steps 1-3 are sufficient in latest VS2019, which has `ctrl` + `/` as the Global default for `Edit.ToggleLineComments`.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022, `<CTRL> /` was not a Global Default.

Answer (score 1):

In **Visual studio 2022** you also need to install the `workload` for ASP.NET and webdevelopment if you want to use the shortcut for `Edit.ToggleBlockComment`, as is explained [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-key-combinationctrlk-ctrlcis-bound-to-commandc/1294543#T-N1309029). If this workload is not installed then pressing CTRL + K will generate an error message in the bottom left of the IDE that says something like `The key combination (Ctrl-K, ....) is bound to command (....) which is not currently available.`

You can search for the required workload by entering `web workload` in the searchbar at the top of the IDE. The workload should pop up as a search suggestion. To install this workload you need 2 GB of free diskspace on your computer. Alternatively you can also install the workload with the `Visual studio installer` app. You can easily find and open this app using the search bar of windows. Once the app has started click on `Modify`. Then under the tab Workloads select the workload `ASP.net and web development` and press `Modify` in the bottom right. Visual studio needs to be closed before you can start the workload installation.

When you've installed the workload for webdevelopment in ASP.NET, Javascript/HTML the shortcuts should work. You can change the shortcut of `Edit.ToggleBlockComment` to `CTRL + /` by going to `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard` where you can assign the shortcut. You can leave the `Use new shortcut in` field on `Global`. After that you can use `CTRL+/` to both comment as well as uncomment a line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the same in 2012 but in 2015 you can.

Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

Either, find "VisualD.ToggleCommentSelection" or
Search for "comment" and the bottom option should be "VisualD.ToggleCommentSelection"

[Snip showing how to set toggle comment shortcut.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMDsp.png)

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio 2019 this works by default using `Ctrl + K` and then `Ctrl + /`

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio 2022, you can find an extension to toggle blocks of comments. I use Toggle Comment 2022 and it's pretty straight forward. Ctrl+/ comment and uncomment.

[image: icon of the extension]